# Request size error while inserting record to BigQuery using Streaming_insert beam api in dataflow

Tags: java, google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a google dataflow streaming job to read from PubSub and insert into BigQuery. I am using STREAMING_INSERT api to insert JSON data to BiqQuery table. I am facing insertion issue stating request size is more than the permissible limit of 10 Mb. The dataflow error is as shown below. The size per record is 1-2Mb and based on my understanding dataflow jobs inserts streaming data as micro batch which is causing this error.

Could you please provide some resolution for this.

> Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: We have
> observed a row that is 24625273 bytes in size. BigQuery supports
> request sizes up to 10MB, and this row is too large. You may change
> your retry strategy to unblock this pipeline, and the row will be
> output as a failed insert.
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1088)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1242)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.flushRows(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:403)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.access$900(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:67)

Code snippet for BigQuery insert is as follows

```
.apply(
        "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withAutoSharding()
                .withoutValidation()
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                .to(options.getOutputTableSpec()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BQ write operation is running into a known limitation of the BQ streaming inserts API. Basically, each batch of data written from Dataflow to BQ using streaming inserts has to be less than 10MB in size.

Dataflow tries to keep batches under this limit. But if a single row is larger than 10MB, then Dataflow cannot stay under this limit and hence may run into this issue. Can that be the case ?

Another option might be to use the [BQ File Loads-based write method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a6e25ae421ccd9c85e4fbc69c6ddcd686e22495b/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1954) instead of streaming inserts.

Storage Write API based write mode unfortunately has the same limitation currently.

Comment: @chamikara- Thankyou for the response. As you mentioned I will have to proceed with wither Storage_write_api or File_Load api. Could you provide some insight on both options, considering a streaming dataflow pipeline and having records of size more than 10 mb.

Comment: Either option should work for your case. If you are using File_load API, you will have to set a triggering frequency (subjected to daily load job quota). Storage Write API should provide a better latency guarantee and possibly a more smoother BQ dataset for any downstream consumers.

Comment: I was made aware that the Storage Write API based write mode has the same limitation, so updated the answer to reflect that.